# javascript/jquery code not working - limit to how many calls can be made in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code I am using from jquery ui tabs:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        // Tabs
        $('#tabs1').tabs();
        $('#tabs2').tabs();
        $('#tabs3').tabs();

        //hover states on the static widgets
        $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
        },function() {
            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this page: http://sekhu.net/charlie/index.php

Now Most of the jquery calls work, but this one in particular only works depending on where I place it amongst the other init. I'm using Sudo Slider jQuery Plugin and the jquery tabs to include the tabs in the slide. Is this not possible, or have I made an error somewhere? Perhaps missing a ; or something?

I'm new to jquery/script so I have no clue what's gone wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I can't seem to find any element of #dialog_link or #icons on the page provided?

Comment: thanks joseph I think you spotted my inept mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I think the last `});` should be `})();`

But I might be confusing it with the self-executing anonymous functions

Comment: ah i think i fixed it, though not quite sure how. Many thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

The order you do things is often critical in JavaScript, especially if you are  adding events to anchors loaded dynamically.  You need to do things in this order:

1. retrieve data with a dynamic AJAX call
2. process the data and display the results which may include a list of anchors
3. install listeners for events like click and hover on the anchors displayed
   in #2.

If you try to install the listeners before you've displayed the data, they won't listen.  So don't install the listeners in a document.ready() or init() function, install them in the callback of the function that loads the dynamic data the listeners apply to.  Something like this

```
$.get('myUrl',function(data){         // get dynamic data
    var anchorList = myProcess(data); // create a menu from the dynamic data
    $('#myTarget').html(anchorList);  // display the menu
    $('#myTarget a').hover( ... );    //  *now* install the listeners
    $('#myTarget a').click( ... );
});
```